# GitHub Workflow for Configuration Variants?

Tags: git, version-control

My work group releases embedded software for a commercial product.  We have been using ClearCase for a very long time, but I am investigating a more modern tool such as Git, with GitHub Enterprise.  There is one part of our process that I am struggling with, understanding how it would translate from CC to Git.

Our core software (the "Algorithm") is mostly common across the different variations of product we release.  However, each product may have a different configuration, and a different set of tuning values that go with it.

So in ClearCase, we have a folder called "Algo" which stores common code.  And we have a folder called "Cal" in the same repository which contains the variant specific stuff, such as tuning files.

When we release, for production, we release Algo files from our mainline.  Cal files are released from a project specific branch, so you might have WidgetA.2016 and WidgetB.2016 branches.

Now, in Git, if I understand it correctly, all the files are tracked together as a project.

So what are some good straightforward workflows in Git which would respect our need to have common Algo files, and variations in Cal files?  So far, what I have come up with seems cumbersome: keep a branch for each Widget, and have to pull/merge constant to keep in sync with Master?

Or a fork for each Widget?

Or do I put Algo in one repo and Cal in a second repo?  How would we manage tags and releases that way?

Comment: Git is tool - replaceent for CC, GitHub is not tool, but service (and not related to question and problem)

Comment: I will edit for correct terminology.

Comment: I found useful similar discussion here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/207014/organizing-a-git-repository-with-several-projects-sharing-code?rq=1